# Three.js Getting translateZ values [three.js]

Tags: javascript, three.js

I couldn't seem to find the proper answer anywhere on here, nor did I manage to come up with the solutions for a calculations myself. I'm trying to find the position values that a 'object.translateZ(-100)' would provide, but without doing it. The reason for this is I want to animate and object flying towards the camera, but stopping Z-100 in front of it - using Tween.js:

```
new TWEEN.Tween( object.position )
    .to( {x: camera.position.x, y: camera.position.y, z: (camera.position.z)}, 2000 )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
    .start();
new TWEEN.Tween( object.rotation )
    .to( {x: camera.rotation.x, y: camera.rotation.y, z: (camera.rotation.z)}, 2000 )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
    .start()
    .onComplete(function(){
        object.updateMatrix();
        object.translateZ(-500);
    });
```

Right now it tweens, lands at the camera and then translates back to the correct position. So I basically need to figure out another target position than 'camera.position', but rather one that is "translateZ(-500)" from that. Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the position that `obj.translateZ(-100)` would move `obj` to, you can easily find this point by manipulating THREE.js vectors. Consider the following:

```
let pos = new THREE.Vector3();            // Create a new empty 3D vector
obj.getWorldPosition(pos);                // Set pos to be obj's world position
pos.add(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -100));   // Add (0,0,-100) to pos
```

Now, `pos` should contain the point you are looking for, and you can easily create your vector object as follows: `{x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z: pos.z}`.

Did I understand your intention correctly?